# react navigation v5 @react-navigation/drawer check drawer open

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v5

so in react navigation v5 how to check if drawer open or not 
not that i use custom drawer 
  `drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerComponent {...props} />}`

`const isDrawerOpen = useIsDrawerOpen()` i can not use this from

Comment: You got any solution buddy ?

Answer (score 0):

`useIsDrawerOpen()` **is a Hook to detect if the drawer is open in a parent navigator.**

For exemple in your view you can test if your drawer is open or not directly using this approach :

```
import { useIsDrawerOpen } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const MainContainer = () => {
   return (
    <View style={(useIsDrawerOpen()) ? styles.conatinerOpenStyle : styles.containerClosedStyle}>
        <Text>{console.log("Test drawer  "+useIsDrawerOpen())}</Text>

    </View>
);}
```

And it will indicate to you the state of your drawer.

Comment: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function

i need to call useIsDrawerOpen  inside render is there any way to do that